# Show uniform convergence of a series of complex function on every compact subset

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f:B(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function. Suppose $\sum^\infty_{n=0}f^{(n)}(0)$ converges absolutely.

Show that there exists an entire function $g(z)$ such that $g(z)=f(z)$ for all $z\in B(0,1)$ and the series of functions $\sum^\infty_{n=0}g^{(n)}$ converges uniformly on every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ where $a_n= f^{(n)}(0)/n!$, so $f^{(n)}(0)= a_nn!$. By assumption you have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|n!<\infty$. We want to show that the powerseries of $f$ has radius of convergence equal to $\infty$, so it can be extended to an entire function. For fixed $z\in \mathbb C$ we have
$$\frac{|a_{n}z^n|}{|a_nn!|}= \frac{|z|^n}{n!}$$
where the latter converges to $0$ as $n\to \infty$. Since $\sum |a_nn!|$ converges, it follows that $\sum |a_nz^n|$ converges, using the limit comparison test for series.